# Android - JQUERY problem on Webview using loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: jquery, android, html, webview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to show a jquery mobile webpage on my  webview, but I'm having problems with some events, for example: This is the test webpage that I'm trying to show :

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#one

When I use this :

```
webView.loadUrl("http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#one");
```

I don't have any problem rendering the page also the events works fine, but I need to use **loadDataWithBaseURL** instead **loadUrl** on my application.

When I use this :

```
String htmlData = convertStreamToString(getAssets().open("page.txt"));
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#one", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Where **page.txt** is the source code of the page and **htmlData** the html code in String.
It renders the page, click on `Show page "two"` works well also `back to page one`, but I have problem when I enter to `Show page "popup"` , the close button for the popup doesn't work neither `Back to page "one"` button in the dialog.

Anybody know what could be happen?
Thanks!

Comment: Solved!, I added the historyUrl the same as the baseUrl and works!

Comment: So Please Answer it yourself and and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!, I added the historyUrl the same as the baseUrl and works!

```
final String baseURL = 
"http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#one";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseURL, htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", baseURL);
```

Comment: you must post code after you got the solution so that other people can also get to know :